# Importing custom built pip installed tensorflow to conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm a newbie to python and tensorflow and after installing a custom wheel version of **tensorflow 1.5.0** using pip install, I created a conda environment using Pycharm. On activating the environment, I observed that the tensorflow isn't one of its packages.

Am just wondering if there was any way I could import the pip installed tensorflow package into the environment without building it with conda and reinstalling it in the environment? Thanks

**Edited:**

> Discovered that you have to install it in the new environment before
>   you can use it

Comment: have you installed the tensorflow pip package inside the new conda environment or in base environment? Did you check by importing tensorflow?

Comment: I imported it in the base conda environment in C:/users/username/Anaconda3. When I do "conda list", I see a lot listed including tensorflow but I repeat that for an environment I created, I see only like 10 packages excluding tensorflow. I just figured that it just installed in the base env and I'm asking if I could import into the new conda env without reinstalling it in the new conda env? @AravindhKuppusamy

Comment: I don't think you can use the package installed in the different environment. You can always install it in the new environment you created.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thanks @AravindhKuppusamy